# Angular 2 / .NET Core Progress bar

Tags: c#, angular, api, .net-core, progress-bar

I have this project going on where I make a call from my `Angular 2 site` to create some `Entity entries in my database`. 
The `backend API` takes about 2 minutes  to finish the job and then return the result.

Currently I am displaying a loading animation on my frontend so the user knows that something is still going on. But because of the time needed I want to change this to a `progress bar`.

I know I can use Angular Material to implement a progress bar and I can update it with values to show the progress. 
My question however is the following:

After making the call to the backend API, how do I send updates (sort of a counter++ thing) to my frontend to update the progress bar?

```
// PUT: api/admin/lorem
[HttpPut]
[Route("route")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAndCalculateStuff([FromBody]Model model) {
    var lorem = await ipsum(model);
    return NoContent(); 
    // NoContent is currently a placeholder, I want to place my counter++ here
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to do it like that. Not only your database is likely to not be reporting progress % to insert X amount of records - WebApi also can't be sending responses whilst the job is being executed. It is wasted effort if this is just for progress bar but if you really wanted to achieve this you would need to come up with a Fire and Forget mechanism which issues a receipt for a job and then another endpoint which you can query that receipt about the progress.

Comment: I am currently looking to implement Hangfire in the project after I saw your comment and with it I can Fire & Forget a job which result in a jobId. Not sure if I can then use this jobId to track the status, still need to read the documentation on it first

Comment: Yes, you can with Hangfire. But how do you plan to track progress of how many records have been processed by the database? Your plan hinges on the assumption that the DBMS has some way of tracking progress of SQL query execution. None to my knowledge have that. I think you are barking up the wrong tree here trying to solve this problem with the progress bar.

Comment: I'm not specifically trying to track the SQL query execution. Once my calculations have been done, I then add a new entry into the database. So I can just put a counter++ option after each creation of a db entry and track that status change with Hangfire. At least in theory :)

Comment: Yes, you can. But be aware that this will require a fair amount of effort for potentially minimal gain in user experience. You are changing the architecture of your solution just for that.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius It's a future ToDo for my project :) Added a simple loading gif with the message "This proces will take a while, please be patient."  for now. The users using it know they have to wait a bit and I'll do some testing to see it using Hangfire for something like this actually works or if I should just abandon the idea altogether.  Thanks for the usefull info though, learned a couple of interesting things in the proces ^^ Not sure how to close this question or mark as solved now though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169710/discussion-between-vidmantas-blazevicius-and-haraldur).

Comment: I think you are missing something in your code here. `var lorem = await ipsum(model);` isn't reporting any progress so you would have nothing to report back to the client, even if you had a mechanism to do so. As @VidmantasBlazevicius mentioned, generally your first endpoint starts the job and returns a JobID to the client. The client then polls the API using that JobID until the job is complete. I've also used WebSocket to monitor many jobs when they have wildly varying completion times. [Something like this](https://github.com/DeanPDX/go-websocket-job-runner).

Comment: @Haraldur HTTP doesn't allow the server to send an infinite stream of messages to the client. Web API can't do what HTTP doesn't allow. There *are* ways to send messages to the client using WebSockets, long polling or Server-side events. The easiest way to do this would be to use `SingalR`, which uses all of the above techniques underneath, to send events to the client. The Javascript handler that receives those events would have to update the progressbar

Comment: @Haraldur check for example [.NET Core with SignalR and Angular - Real-Time Charts](https://code-maze.com/netcore-signalr-angular/).

Comment: @Haraldur I built something similar with React a while back, not that it matters. The browser sends a file to the controller that requires some heavy processing. This takes 2+ minutes, so it can't be done in the action itself. It's sent to a `BackgroundService` for processing instead. That service posts events to a SignalR hub addressed to the original caller at various points. The client-side code receives those events and updates the UI - a grid with the data, scrolling log with the text and a progress bar with the number of processed records

Comment: @Haraldur when the page starts, it establishes a SignalR connection and just waits for events.

Answer (score -1):

I recently saw an example of this which looked a bit wrong but i guess it worked. The example used two functions; one to kick off the initial functionality and the other to request the status of that functionality. So in CreateAndCalculateStuff() you can update a global variable and in the second you return that global variable.

Comment: This is not a good suggestion. The OP is using WebApi (RESTful) which is kind of aimed to be completely stateless and your suggestion is to introduce a global state. Also, if you refer to external material - it is adviced to include links to it.