# How to make progress-bar in angular 2 and .net core

Tags: c#, angular, signalr, progress-bar

I'm trying to create a progressbar in .netCore and in Angular 8.
The server, .net core, has a loop to make all persons document and I want to show making progress in the angular side.
e.g. loop 65/100 => 65%

In angular side I make a server like this:

```
public download(fileName: string): Observable<DownloadResponse> {
 let downloadURL = `urlToDownloadDocument`;

return this.httpClient.get(downloadURL, {
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events'
  , responseType: 'blob'
}).pipe(map((event) => {
  this.downloadResponse.status = event.type;

  switch (event.type) {

    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      this.downloadResponse.filePath = null;
      return this.downloadResponse;

    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
      this.downloadResponse.message = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total).toString() + '%';
      this.downloadResponse.filePath = null;
      return this.downloadResponse;

    case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
        this.downloadResponse.message = 'Finished';
        this.downloadResponse.filePath = event.url;
        return this.downloadResponse;

    case HttpEventType.Response:
        this.downloadResponse.message = 'Transfering';
        this.downloadResponse.filePath = event.url;
        this.downloadResponse.body = event.body;
        this.Transfer(event.body, fileName);

      return this.downloadResponse;
    default:
      this.downloadResponse.message = `Unhandled Case ${event.type}`;
      this.downloadResponse.filePath = null;
      return this.downloadResponse;
  }
})
);
}

private Transfer(blob: Blob, fileName){
  let link = document.createElement('a');
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  link.click();
}
```

And in .net has a controller which returns an FileStramResult

```
public IActionResult getAllDocument(...){
    ...
    return File(stream, "application/zip", "Documents.zip");
}
```

I think that an "observe: 'events'" in angular just get actions in the browser and can't observe actions in the .net server.
I searched about signarlR to get communications between both side but I couldn't find any article saying about download progressbar in Angular 2 and in .netCore beside of this link [Angular 2 / .NET Core Progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995761/angular-2-net-core-progress-bar)
that seek to find a way to calculate a progress in a query and don't say about how to show a progress in a view.

Comment: Why are you looping on the server side?

Comment: @thenolin Is the loop to make a person documents. e.g. for (p in persons){ makeApdf(p) }

Comment: Sorry, not super familiar w/ signalr.. If I were you I would loop in the client, send a request once it's done to build the document. That would make it easier to display the progress bar. Not sure if that's possible though for you

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.
After reading this tutorial about signalR and Angular 2
https://rukshan.dev/2019/05/how-to-notify-your-angular-7-app-using-signalr
I changed a little bit

IHub:

```
Task DownloadResponseMessage(string message, int percentage);

Task GetConnectionId();
```

(someClass : Hub<...>):

```
public string GetConnectionId()
{
    var result = Context.ConnectionId;
    return result;
}
```

to Send the progress:

```
_hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).DownloadResponseMessage(message, percentage);
```

And in Angular:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .withUrl("http://localhost:5627/download")
      .build();

    this.connection.start().then(function () {
      console.log('Connected!');
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });

    console.log(this.connection);

    this.connection.on("DownloadResponseMessage", (message: string, percentage: number) => {
      this.message = message;
      this.percentage = percentage;
    });

  }

  getConnectionId(){

    return this.connection.invoke("GetConnectionId")
      .then((connectionId:any) => {
        console.log(connectionId);
        this.connectionId = connectionId;
      },
      e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }

  click(){
    this.getConnectionId().then(() => {
      this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:5627/api/message?connectionId="+this.connectionId).subscribe();
    })

  }
```